# Higher Order Function with Case Class Method

Tags: scala, higher-order-functions, abstraction, case-class

I am trying to remove redundancy in my code. I think I can do it with higher order functions.

What I want to do is factor out the common bits into f3, then just make the bits that are different between f1 and f2 be parameters that are passed into f3.

```
object Example extends App {

  case class action(name: String, age: Int) {
    def setName(new_name: String): action = this.copy(name = new_name)
    def setAge(new_age: Int): action = this.copy(age = new_age)
  }

  def f1(x: action, increment: Int) = {
    // big block of code which does a....

    // a single line in the block calling
    val older_person = x setAge (x.age + increment)

    // big block of code which does b....
  }

  def f2(x: action, new_name: String) = {
    // big block of code which does a....

    // a single line in the block calling
    val new_name_person = x setName new_name

    // big block of code which does b....
  }

  /* Now as there is clearly a redundancy, which can be solved by higher order functions.
    I want to combine f1 and f2 into a single function. The function will take in the action, the value, and the 
    function to apply. It will then call the relevant function inside the method.
   */
  def f3[T](x: action)(f: T => action)(value: T) = {
   // big block of code which does a....
   // call x.f(value)
    val new_action = ??? 
   // big block of code which does b....
  }

  // then in my code I can call like this:
  // f3(x)(setAge)(100)
  // f3(x)(setName("new_name")
}
```

What I am confused about is how can I pass in a function that is a method inside the case class? Is there anyway to do this in an elegant way?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

In `f3`, you can simply accept a function of type `Action => Action` (I'm going to use `Action` instead of `action` to make it less confusing).

```
def f3(x: Action)(copy: Action => Action) = {
  // big block of code which does a....

  // a single line in the block calling
  val new_name_person = copy(x)

  // big block of code which does b....
}
```

Then you can define a few helpful functions and use currying to make them easier to use later:

```
object Action {
  def setName(name: String)(action: Action) = action.copy(name=name)
  def incAge(inc: Int)(action: Action) = action.copy(age=action.age+inc)
}
```

And then use it like this:

```
val x = Action("Foo", 42)
f3(x)(Action.incAge(100))
f3(x)(Action.setName("new_name"))
```

[Try it in Scastie](https://scastie.scala-lang.org/1dSmQFLVQ1qmFUq82RW4GQ)